# Builder design pattern (car, wheels)

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to understand the Builder design pattern.

The following classes are at play: `Vehicle`, contains a List of wheels (`List<Wheel>`). I have an abstract builder (`VehicleBuilder`) from which inherits `RegularCarBuilder`.

I am struggling with the concept of 2 ideas:

1. the wheels are "new"ed inside the `RegularCarBuilder.SetWheels()` method. Now, if I want the user of the builder class to be able to specify a property of the wheels that will be created, for example, the manufacturer. how would I do this? this means that the client will need to pass this information before or at the point of creating the vehicle. but where?
2. Do I really need a director class? I guess I could move the algorithm of order of creation into the builder class itself.

   > abstract class VehicleBuilder
   >       {
   >           public abstract Vehicle GetVehicle();
   >           public abstract void SetEngine();
   >           public abstract void SetWheels();
   >       }

Comment: Show some of your code. From what you write I am not sure if what you have is a builder or just an abstract factory.

Comment: You don't always need a separate construct for the Director.  The `StringBuilder` class is a builder pattern where the client is the Director.

Comment: For your first question, I would probably do something like `new RegularCarBuilder().SetWheelManufacturer(...).AddWheel().AddWheel()...`. The builder is responsible for enforcing the protocol, i.e. that `SetWheelManufacturer()` has been called before `AddWheel()`.

Comment: Nico Schertler, this would suggest very troublesome code for the user. he would need to know all the properties that he must set. basically this means that he is going to need to know the order of creation, and i thought that the idea of builder is to abstract this from the user. isn't it ?